# Python- Item not in list (but it is)-Copying lists

Tags: python

I am working on an algorithm that is using a leaderboard of peptides and removes the peptides that don't have a particular "score". I'm currently struggling to understand why I keep getting an error regarding my removal process. I believe it *may* have to do with my copying of lists, which I then use in my removal process. However, I have used this same process in previous problems, with no problem, so I don't understand why this particular instance is throwing an error.

```
def Trim(Leaderboard,Spectra,N):
     Scores=[];droplist=[]
     for peptide in Leaderboard:
         Scores.append(LinearScore(peptide,Spectra))
     Leaderboard,Scores = zip(*sorted(zip(Leaderboard, Scores),key=lambda peptide: peptide[1], reverse=True))
     Leaderboard=list(Leaderboard);Scores=list(Scores) ### IS THIS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS????
     Cutoffscore=Scores[N-1] # Here I am finding the Score of the Nth' peptide (in sorted order)
     for peptide,score in zip(Leaderboard,Scores): # iterate through list of tuples
         if score<Cutoffscore: # if peptide score is lower than cut off score
             droplist.append(peptide) # remove that peptide from the leaderboard
     for i in droplist:
        Leaderboard.remove(i) ### ERROR THROWN HERE "Error list.remove(x), x not in list"
     return Leaderboard # then return what's left of the list
```

Edit: Problem was located elsewhere in the program

Comment: Can you post a snippet of data so that people can test?

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to remove something that has already been removed?

Comment: Can you `add peptides` you *want to keep* to a new list? Or do you have to remove them? You may want to be careful with taking a `list` as an input argument and then returning it, have you heard of modifying variables `in place`? You could see some behaviour you don't expect. Also to have a few blank lines in the code separating different bits that do stuff looks nice :P I do it anyway.

Comment: no its not .... python doesnt lie to you ... if it says something is not in a list , then that thing is not in that list

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [peptide for peptide,score in zip(Leaderboard,Scores) if score >= CutoffScore]
```

is a much nicer way to accomplish this ... that said you should iterate over droplist backwards

```
for i in reversed(droplist):
    Leaderboard.remove(i)
```

the problem is that

consider the case where you have scores `[1,5,5,5,5,5,1]` ... your indexes in droplist are `[0, 6]`

however once you pop 0... there is no index 6 ... your other index has shifted to 5

Comment: Your first code block (list = [peptide for peptide...]), would I even need to have a drop list if I used that?

Comment: no that creates a new list only with peptides that score better than your cutoff ...